# gives Garbage value

Tags: java, arrays

See this program code:

public class RemoveTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


System.out.print(remove(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4}));


}

static int [] remove(int[] a){
    int[] b = new int[a.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(a, 1, b, 0, a.length - 1);
    return b;

}
```

}

But gives the Garbage output. I am trying it on Eclipse IDE

Comment: That's not garbage, that's how objects are printed. What kind of a result were you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've seen the results of [`Object`'s `toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29); arrays are objects too.

Use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29):

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(remove(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4})));
```